# How to get eloquent collection of parent table while applying where clause to its child table

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5.7

I have 2 tables. **projects** and **project_categories**. The later table has a foreign key *project_id* that corresponds to **projects** table. Both have a one-to-one relationship and for some reason I want project category information to be in a different table.

Now, I would like to let users browse projects by category. If category was part of **projects** table then I would simply apply a *where* clause to get projects for a selected category. Is there any clean way offered by eloquent/query builder that would get a collection of **projects** table that have category from **project_categories** table? Again, **project_categories** has a foreign key *project_id* that links it to **projects** table.

I have spent quite some time trying to find a neat solution but to no avail so far. Your help would be really appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After failing to find a built in functionality out of the box from eloquent, I arrived at the decision that eloquent actually doesn't go beyond relationships between tables. And this task can only be achieved using **joins**.

However, Laravel still offers a pretty neat syntax for using table joins. Laravel provides this trough the **DB Facade**. Here's a simple example of joins that can effectively address the above question probably in the most efficient way possible with relational databases.

```
$projects = DB::table('projects')
            ->join('project_categories', 'projects.id', '=', 'project_categories.project_id')
            ->where('project_categories.main_category',$request->get('mc'))
            ->select('projects.*')
            ->get();
```

**Note!** Don't forget to bring in *DB Facade*

The above statement does exactly what's been asked. In justification for why this might be the most efficient way that exist for such use cases in relational databases, is the fact that this statement will query the database only once. Hope this helps someone.